# Growl style notifications that are library/framework independent?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Are there any framework independent javascript growl style notification libraries? Most everything I've found (jGrowl, Gritter, etc.) relies on jQuery or some other major library. I need this as part of a drop-in widget I'm developing and it needs to be as lightweight as possible, and I don't want to introduce dependencies on another library.

I'd like to avoid writing this part from scratch. I suppose I could gut one of the jQuery based options and jQuery dependencies into only what's necessary.

Comment: This isn't answer, hence the comment, but adding jQuery as a dependency seems like a small price to pay for what you get.  Especially since you can just pull it off a CDN and be done.  Of course, you could have other constraints keeping you from doing this but wanted to mention that jQuery is a very small library that stays out of the way unless used.

Comment: I'm with Gregg on this one. You will have a hard time finding something like this because you are in the minority (people not using a library). Better off just writing it yourself or including a library. I'm sure there are other things in your application that could be improved with jQuery.

Comment: The library that this will be part of may be using jquery, dojo, etc. I want to avoid dependency collisions and only need basic dom selection and some animation. My in the middle approach is to detect whether or not jQuery has been loaded already and load it if it hasn't been. If they are not using jQuery though and already using another library, seems hefty to require jQuery for this

Comment: I don't know of any, but rolling your own shouldn't be incredibly difficult - especially if you don't use animation.  Cross-browser DOM manipulation is a pain in the butt, but is a relatively straightforward concept.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one: [Humane-JS](https://github.com/wavded/humane-js)

I haven't got a chance to use it yet but I like the demos.

Answer (score 1):

how about this one? [Smoke.js](https://github.com/jyoungblood/smoke.js)

Answer (score 0):

5 years late but well I recently made one a couple of weeks ago. It's also customizable as in you can override it with your custom css and/or make resuable presets too.
[It's on my github](https://github.com/binarybaba/prophetjs)