# Javascript alert suppresses other javascript functions

Tags: javascript, alert

I have the following problem: I want to warn a user about an upcoming session timeout with an alert. When the actual session timeout happens, I want to pop-up another alert and forward to any website. My approach works with Firefox and IE. With Safari and Chrome, when I don't submit the first alert before the second timeout happens, the second function is never executed, actually. Any hints?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Session timeout in 5 minutes...');
}, 30 * 1000);


setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Session timeout, sorry');
    location.href = 'http://google.com';      
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Maybe using custom alert dialogs (HTML, CSS) would be a better here.

Comment: Like this one : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Thank you, the jquery dialog did it!

Answer (score 1):

An alert pauses your javascript execution. It's considered more UI friendly to use a [Growl](http://growl.info/) or top-bar message type of notification.

edit:
There are loads of libraries for this, but that's part of another question.
[Growl style notifications that are library/framework independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400113/growl-style-notifications-that-are-library-framework-independent)

Answer (score 0):

This issue would be solved by creating a custom alert box. 
But Incase you want to do it with the broswer alert box, you can try this.

```
var nStartTime = new Date().getTime();

setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Session timeout in 5 minutes...');
    var nRemainingTime = 60 * 1000 -  (new Date().getTime() - nStartTime);
    nRemainingTime = nRemainingTime < 0 ? 0 : nRemainingTime ;
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Session timeout, sorry');
        location.href = 'http://google.com';         
    }, nRemainingTime); 
}, 30 * 1000);var nStartTime = new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

alert() and confirm() are two prompts which stops the java script execution.